# Is it true that for a structure $\mathcal A$ we have $\mbox{Th}(\mathcal A)$ is r.e. iff it is recursive

Tags: proof-verification, logic, first-order-logic, proof-theory

Given a language $\mathcal L$ and a structure $\mathcal A$ compatible with it, then we call $\mbox{Th}(\mathcal A) = \{ \varphi \mid \mathcal A \models \varphi \}$ the theory of $\mathcal A$; where $\varphi$ denotes a sentence in $\mathcal L$.

*Proposition*: If $\mbox{Th}(\mathcal A)$ is recursively enumerable, then it is decidable.

*Proof*: Suppose we have an algorithm that given $\varphi$ accepts it $\varphi \in \mbox{Th}(\mathcal A)$ and diverges otherwise. Consider the complement of $\mbox{Th}(\mathcal A)$ in the set of all sentences. This set is precisely $\{ \varphi \mid \mathcal A \models \neg \varphi \}$, so we just have to put a negation in front of the sentence, and use our algorithm for the resulting sentence, hence this complement is recursively enumerable. $\square$

So for $\mbox{Th}(\mathcal A)$ the notions of r.e. and recursive are the same (basically because it is [complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_theory)). Is this right? Is my proof correct? I am learning about logic now, and sometimes I get easily confused, and if the above is true then this seems to be a nice little fact, but I nowhere can find it stated...

Comment: Yes. This is the standard way completeness is used in this sort of scenario, by the way. For instance, this is the reason why a, say, $\Sigma^1_n$ well-ordering of the reals is actually $\Delta^1_n$ and so on.

Comment: Yes, the result is certainly true. Is your proof correct? That seems like a trickier question: Reading what you wrote it does seem like you understand why the result is true. But the way you wrote it is extremely bad - if I didn't already understand how to prove the result I'd have no idea what you meant by the sentence "So for our algorithm...".

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks for your feedback, I added a line explaining what I mean with "our algorithm".

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Feel free to give more details, I confess I do not really know what you mean with a $\Sigma_n^1$-well ordering...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your result is correct, and the proof looks valid.

For coursework, you should probably explicitly call out that you're using the result that if a set and its complement are both r.e. then they are decidable.

(Particularly pedantic teachers may say, "complement with respect to what", so in order to get absolutely all of the details right, you should specify checking that the input is actually a well-formed sentence before you blindly stick a negation in front of it. But most probably you can get away with leaving that kind of busywork for the reader to imagine).